# What 3rd party platform support custom camera application?

Tags: iphone, cordova, coronasdk

I'm making an app with CoronaSDK for custom camera button, frame and layout like "Leme Camera" in app store.
However, they don't support camera buffer so we can't use custom layout to control capturing camera which is not acceptable.
What I found out is PhoneGap also lack that feature. They show native camera window when I tap
Can anyone recommend other cross platform framework for that feature?

Answer (score 1):

With the PhoneGap platform you are able to use a combination of objective C and the PhoneGap standard javascript library. 
From what you have described, it sounds like you would want to go native for something like this!  Most of all of these third party SDKs do not get very good performance but if you were to write the small computationally intensive camera part in objective C you get all the resources you need and are able to cut back on the amount of code you will need to port when you try to support additional platforms.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Kurt. I just tested MoSync & Titanium. They both support custom camera layout that's all I need. So I will go with either one.